# Segmentation fault using GstDiscoverer (GStreamer)

Tags: c++, windows, segmentation-fault, gstreamer

I am writing desktop app for windows on C++ using Qt for GUI and GStreamer for audio processing.

In my app I need to monitor several internet aac audio streams if they are online, and listen to available stream that has the most priority. For this task I use GstDiscoverer object from GStreamer, but I have some problems with it.

I check audio streams every 1-2 seconds, so GstDiscoverer is called very often.
And every time my app is running, eventually it will crash with segmentation fault error during GstDiscoverer check.

I tried both sync and async methods of calling GstDiscoverer ( gst_discoverer_discover_uri(), gst_discoverer_discover_uri_async() ) , both work the same way.

The crash happens in aac_type_find() function from gsttypefindfunctions.c on line 1122 (second line of code below).

```
len = ((c.data[offset + 3] & 0x03) << 11) |
       (c.data[offset + 4] << 3) | ((c.data[offset + 5] & 0xe0) >> 5);
```

Local variables received from debugger during one of crashes:
[image]

As we can see, offset variable is greater than c.size, so c.data[offset] is out of range, I think that's why segmentation fault happens.
This happens not regularly. The program can work several hours or ten minutes.
But it seems to me that it happens more often if time interval between calls of GstDiscoverer is little. So, there is some probability of crash calling aac_type_find().

I tried GStreamer versions 1.6.1 and latest 1.6.2, the bug exists in both.

Can somebody help me with this problem? Is this Gstreamer bug or maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Please report this, ideally with a test case and sample file, to the GStreamer developers. A crash is always something to fix in the software you're using, and something you should report to the developers for that. You can do so here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer

Comment: @SebastianDröge: Reported: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was reported to the GStreamer project here and a patch for the crash was merged and will be in the next releases: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759910